# Quadratic programming problem involving permutation matrices

Tags: optimization, algorithms, approximation, quadratic-programming

Does anyone know a good algorithm for quickly finding an approximate solution to the following problem?

Given two square matrices $A$ and $B$, minimize $\| P A P^\top - B \|$ over all permutation matrices $P$.

I have heard that there are several types of algorithms for these kinds of problems, like iterative improvement, simulated annealing, tabu search, genetic algorithms, evolution strategies, ant algorithms, and scatter search. I am looking for existing software.

Comment: How big are the matrices $A$ and $B$, typically?

Comment: For vertex-ordering problems: for theoretical results try [Flow Metrics](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=author%3Avempala+author%3Abornstein+flow+metrics&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5) (LP-based algorithms, subsequent theoretical improvements use SDPs).  In practice, in my experience, the best approach for our problems was to use [METIS](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/overview) (or in our case H-METIS) as the basis of a divide-and-conquer algorithm (nearly linear time), followed by iterations of local improvement.  But that might not work for you depending on A and B.

Comment: What *norm* is this?  I can think of a few thinks for $||A||$: least squares, max, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I will check METIS. The matrices will be up to 500 by 500. I will probably try with a few different norms and see what works best in my case.

Comment: This is a combinatorial problem, not a quadratic program. The feasible set contains $n!$ elements. You're probably stuck with some heuristic to solve it.